# Display horizontal grid lines in nstable view using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

hi i am working with NSTableView in my app.

I want to display grid lines depending on the number of rows but it  shows many lines even when the number of rows are very less.

Is this a usual behavior?

Or am i doing something wrong?
I have checked the horizontal grid lines option from xib.

cannot understand how to achieve this using code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw grid lines in NSTableView only for populated rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606796/draw-grid-lines-in-nstableview-only-for-populated-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue I may say: "YES". It's expected from the NSTableView to be fulfilled of stripes even when empty if you set it so.

I realize that you want also to manage those lines programmatically. Consider check out this method setGridStyleMask:  on the [NSTableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

What I found to work best for me so far is the following code.
Just fool the original grid drawing code to draw only on populated rows.

Subclass NSTableView, if needed and override drawGridInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect as following:

```
- (void)drawGridInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    NSRect lastRowRect = [self rectOfRow:[self numberOfRows]-1];
    NSRect myClipRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, lastRowRect.size.width, NSMaxY(lastRowRect));
    NSRect finalClipRect = NSIntersectionRect(clipRect, myClipRect);
    [super drawGridInClipRect:finalClipRect];
}
```

Comment: I've written a bug to Apple as you shouldn't have to do this.