# Draw grid lines in NSTableView only for populated rows?

Tags: cocoa

How can I draw grid lines in an NSTableView only for rows that are populated? When I set the grid style mask to NSTableViewSolidHorizontalGridStyleMask, it draws grid lines for all rows whether populated or not.

I'm looking for a bit of sample code to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Swift 3.1 this is all that you need:

```
import Cocoa

class GridClipTableView: NSTableView {

    override func drawGrid(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect) { }

}
```

Comment: same with Obj-C: override `drawGridInClipRect:` with an empty method and only item grids will be drawn.

Comment: This worked perfectly - and much cleaner than the other solutions!

Answer (score 44):

What I found to work best for me so far is the following code. Just fool the original grid drawing code to draw only on populated rows.

Subclass NSTableView, if needed, and override drawGridInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect as following:

```
- (void)drawGridInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    NSRect lastRowRect = [self rectOfRow:[self numberOfRows]-1];
    NSRect myClipRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, lastRowRect.size.width, NSMaxY(lastRowRect));
    NSRect finalClipRect = NSIntersectionRect(clipRect, myClipRect);
    [super drawGridInClipRect:finalClipRect];
}
```

Comment: Instead of calculating myClipRect as above, could you just do: NSRect finalClipRect = NSIntersectionRect(clipRect, self.bounds)?

Comment: @sam You could try this but I believe it won't work. It doesn't take the last row location into account. Self is the table view and it may be higher then all the rows in the table.

In fact, clipRect should already be smaller or equal than self.bounds by definition.

Comment: This creates a black colored view in place of the empty white space. I have noticed this problem when I took the xcode update of 5.0.1. Any updated answers?

Comment: In order to also crop the grid after the last column you can use this: `NSRect lastColumnRect = [self rectOfColumn:self.numberOfColumns - 1]; NSRect finalClipRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSMaxX(lastColumnRect), NSMaxY(lastRowRect));`

Comment: Works like charm! You are my time saver!

Comment: I am looking for a one more solution.
I wanna disable a Grid line for Sections. I don't want to get it drawn for sections. I want them only between cells. Any idea ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to subclass `NSTableView` and override [`drawRow:clipRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-BCIBIGJJ). Another possibility would be overriding [`drawGridInClipRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-drawGridInClipRect_), but that's a bit more unwieldy, because you'll have to manually pick out the rows.

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
- (void)drawRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex clipRect:(NSRect)clipRect {
    // First do the default drawing
    [super drawRow:rowIndex clipRect:clipRect];

    // Check if there's content in any of the cells in this row
    BOOL doesHaveContent = NO;
    int numCols = [self numberOfColumns];
    int colIndex;
    for( colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++ ){
        NSCell * cell = [self preparedCellAtColumn:colIndex 
                                               row:rowIndex];
        if( [cell objectValue] != nil ){
            doesHaveContent = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( doesHaveContent ){
        NSRect rowRect = [self rectOfRow:rowIndex];
        NSBezierPath * gridPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        // Ignoring clipRect because this isn't a lot of drawing
        [gridPath moveToPoint:rowRect.origin];
        [gridPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(rowRect.origin.x + rowRect.size.width,
                                          rowRect.origin.y)];
        [gridPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(rowRect.origin.x,
                                          rowRect.origin.y + rowRect.size.height)];
        [gridPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(rowRect.origin.x + rowRect.size.width,
                                          rowRect.origin.y + rowRect.size.height)];
        [myGridColor set];
        [gridPath stroke];
        // You could also just do:
        // [myGridColor set];
        // [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rowRect] stroke];
    }
}
```

Yet another possibility would be to have a custom `NSCell`; each cell could draw a special border around itself if it had content. This wouldn't draw a line across the whole row, though, if there were some cells in the row that were empty.

Comment: Yet another possibility is to resize the table view according to the actual number of rows in its data source.

Comment: @Bavarious: A good point, but it seemed to me that the OP wants empty rows to be present, just not lined.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. DrawRow method is not called at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Neither solution listed here worked for me, for some reason. What I did instead is:

1. Subclass `NSTableView` and override `rectOfColumn:` (see below).
2. Turn on layer backing on the table view, its clip view, and its scroll view (this is required for this solution to work).

This worked from macOS 10.9 up to 10.15 in my tests.

```
- (NSRect)rectOfColumn:(NSInteger)column
{
    NSRect value = [super rectOfColumn:column];

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self numberOfRows];
    if (numberOfRows == 0) {
        value.size.height = 0;
    } else {
        NSRect firstRect = [self rectOfRow:0];
        NSRect lastRect = [self rectOfRow:numberOfRows - 1];

        value.size.height = NSMaxY(lastRect) - NSMinY(firstRect);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: This approach cuts-off also the column separators whereas the other one let them be drawn till the bottom of the table.